# Puzzle of Alphabet addition

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, alphametic

This is an alphametic - Each of the alphabets in the below represents a unique digit in base 10 such that the following representation holds true.

```
            T   E   N
        +   T   E   N
 +  F   O   R   T   Y 
------------------------
   S    I   X   T   Y

(i)   Value of F+Y = ?
(ii)  The value of TOY = ?
(iii) Value of E+O+T = ?
(iv)  Value of R*T = ?
(v)   Value of S+I+X+T+Y = ?
```

Comment: N is 5, rest i am sleepy...

Comment: @ABcDexter I think you're just sleepy.

Comment: @LeppyR64 haha yup!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution:

> ```
>     850 + 
>     850 + 
>   29786 = 
>   31486
> ```
>
> $T = 8, E = 5, N = 0, F = 2, O = 9, R = 7, Y = 6, S = 3. I = 1, X = 4$

Reasoning:

> $N + N + Y$ has the last digit $Y$.
>  This means $N$ is one of $0,5$.
>  but $E+E+T + $(possibly a carriage of 1) has the last digit $T$.
>  The 2 above make me thing that $N = 0$ and $E = 5$

Now we have

> ```
>        T50
>       +T50
>   +  FORTY 
>      -----
>      SIXTY
> ```

Next:

> $O$ has to be a big digit since the value of the 10 thousands changes ($F$ and $S$).
>  Since the max carriage from $T+T+R$ can be $2$, $O$ can be one of $8,9$.
>  but if $O$ is $8$ it means $I$ is $0$ and that cannot be because $N = 0$.
>  So $O=9$ and the carriage from the hundreds must be 2 otherwise $I=0$ that cannot be.
>  In this case $I = 1$.

Now we have:

> ```
>        T50
>       +T50
>   +  F9RTY 
>      -----
>      S1XTY
> ```

Continuing:

> If the carriage return from hundreds must be 2 and we can see that the carriage from the tens is 1 it means that:
>  $T+T+R + 1 >= 20$.
>  This means that $[T,R]$ can be one of $[6, 8], [6,7], [7,6], [7, 8], [8, 4], [8,6], [8,7]$.

Taking one by one:

> $T = 6, R = 8$ can't be because it will result in $X = 1$ but $I = 1$.
>  $T = 6, R = 7$ can't be because it will result in $X = 0$ but $N = 0$.
>  $T = 7, R = 6$ can't be because it will result in $X = 1$ but $I = 1$.
>  $T = 7, R = 8$ results in
>
> ```
>        750
>       +750
>   +  F987Y 
>      -----
>      S137Y
> ```
>
> Since $S = F+1$, we are left with digits $2, 4, 6$  we don't have 2 consecutive digits left.
>  $T = 8, R = 4$ results in $X = 1$ that is not possible because $I = 1$.
>  $T = 8, R = 6$ results in same thing as for $T = 7, R = 8$.
>  $T = 8, R = 7$  we get.
>
> ```
>        850
>       +850
>   +  F978Y 
>      -----
>      S148Y
> ```
>
> We are now left with digits 2,3 and 6 to fill in.
>  Since $S = F+1$ it means $S = 3, F = 2$ and $Y = 6$ and we reach the solution listed above.

Now to answer the questions:

(i)   Value of F+Y = ?

> 8

(ii)  The value of TOY = ?

> 896

(iii) Value of E+O+T = ?

> 22

(iv)  Value of R*T = ?

> 56

(v)   Value of S+I+X+T+Y = ?

> 22

Answer (score 7):

> 850
> +
> 850
> +
> 29786
> =
> 31486

So

> (i) F + Y = 8
> (ii) TOY = 432
> (iii) E + O + T = 22
> (iv) RT = 56
> (v) S + I + X + T + Y = 22

Someone correct me if my mental maths is wrong :)

Comment: I love these puzzles so much

Comment: I believe the last sum should be 22, not 32.

Comment: @gtwebb, thanks for some reason i did F + O + R + T + Y instead of sixty. Oops

Comment: @RahulSinha, is this correct?

Comment: I don't mean to be picky, but I'm going to be (actually I meant it). For alphametic puzzles shouldn't there be a reasoning for the value of the symbols?

Comment: Good point I should have, but seeing as you have already supplied one I won't add one in as it would look like copying, and your explanation is very good. I'll add a small one in

Answer (score 1):

First, $N+N+Y$ yields $Y$.

> So $N+N \in \{0,10\}$ which means that $N \in \{0,5\}$.

If $c_1$ is the carry over from the ones column into the tens, then $c+E+E+T \implies T$.

> This means that $c_1+E+E \in \{0,10\}$.  This is impossible unless $c_1=0$. Therefore, $N=0$ to get no carry over, and $E=5$ since 0 is taken.  The carry over into the hundreds column is then 1.

We also know that

> $1+T+T+R$ can carry over at most 2 if $T$ and $R$ are maxed. Lets call this carry over $c_2$.  Thus, $O+c_2$ carries over, and it can be at most 1.  Thus, $O\in \{8,9\}$, $I\in \{0,1\}$, and $S=F+1$.

But since

> 0 is already taken, we know $I=1$.  Thus, $O=9$ and $c_2=2$.  The lowest value for $X$ is then 2.  Thus, $1+T+T+R \ge 22$.  If $T=8$, then $R \in \{6,7\}$.  If $T=7$, then $R=8$.  $T=6$ does would require $R=9$ which is already taken.

We know that $S$ and $F$ must be

> consecutive, and 7 is already taken.  thus, $S \in \{3,4\}$ and $F \in \{2,3\}$.  In both cases, 3 is taken, so $T=8, R=6$ cannot work because that would make $X=3$.  Similarly, $T=7,R=8$ makes $X=3$, so that is also not an option.

Therefore,

> $T=8$ and $R=7$ which makes $X=4$.  Thus, $S=3$ and $F=2$.  The only remaining value for $Y$ is 6.

Solution is:

> 0=N,  1=I,  2=F,  3=S,  4=X,  5=E,  6=Y,  7=R,  8=T,  9=O
>
>          850
>      +   850
>      + 39786
>      -------
>        41486